# Combining grouped reducers in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, reducers

In Earth Engine, one can easily apply a same reducer to multiple band in an image. Unfortunately, it seems that this nice feature breaks if one uses a [grouped-reducer](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_grouping)?

`repeat()` will work if one seeks to apply the reducer with the same grouping variable on different variables. However, if one wants to apply the reducer on the same variable but with different combining variables (a very typical case for a multi-year land cover area counting), I can't figure out how to use `combine`? I know I could map the grouped reducer for each band, but this would be quite inefficient as the costly reducing operation would be repeated many times, instead of doing the reducing once with many functions.

Here is a test case: compute area of each forest class for multiple year using the vanCutsem forest data. I've tried so far:

- `ee.Reducer.sum().group(1).combine(ee.Reducer.sum().group(2), "secondReducer"),`  but will give: *Reducer.group: Reducer.group groupField out of range*

Code (see https://code.earthengine.google.com/fd81c997990d6d200913c346c379d40f):

```
var geometry =  ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[104.4176, -3.56098],[104.4176, -3.85425],[105.1152, -3.85425],
          [105.1152, -3.56098]]]);

/// Load data
var tmf_annual = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('projects/JRC/TMF/v1_2020/AnnualChanges').
  filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", "AnnualChangesASIA")).
  first())
  var pixel_area_img = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000000).rename("area")  
var input = pixel_area_img.addBands(tmf_annual)

/// One single grouping variable: ok!
var sums = input.select(["area", "Dec1990"]).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1}),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});

print(sums.get("groups"), "means 90")


/// PROBLEM: many  single grouping variable!?
var sums_many = input.select(["area", "Dec1990", "Dec1991"]).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1).
    combine(ee.Reducer.mean().unweighted().group(2), "second"),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});

print(sums_many)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned about this same post on the Earth Engine User's Group, grouped reducers need 2 inputs, but there's no way to share only one of those inputs with other reducers.  To accomplish your task, you need to either replicate and interleave the area image so there are 30 pairs of landcover+area bands and repeat a simple grouped reducer 30 times, or you can just map over the years and run a simple 2-input reducer for each year + the area band.  The cost & runtime of those should be essentially identical, since almost all of the time will be spent in fetching the landcover tiles.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit of tricky one, which i'm not 100% sure why but I think you need to add a dummy band and then roughly follow the approach you already had in mind:

```
var allReducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine(ee.Reducer.sum(), "", true)
var bands = ee.List(["area", "Dec1990", "Dec1991"])
var numbInputs = bands.size();

/// PROBLEM: many  single grouping variable!?
// add a dummy variable band
var sums_many = input.select(bands).addBands(input.select('area')).reduceRegion({
  // reducer: allReducers.repeat(3).group(3, 'group'),
  reducer: allReducers.repeat(numbInputs).group(numbInputs, 'group').unweighted(),
  // reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1).
  //   combine(ee.Reducer.mean().unweighted().group(2), "second"),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e8
}).get('groups');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/508fb57482bae9fd30c5773579213a8a

EDITS 2022-03-25

Perhaps a workaround can be to apply a mapped function for each band:

```
// workaround  solution cam be an iteration:
var iteration = bandGroups.map(function(band){
  var bandOI = input.select(bands)
  
  
  var sums_many = ee.List(bandOI.addBands(input.select(ee.List([band]))).reduceRegion({
    reducer: allReducers.repeat(numbInputs).group(numbInputs, 'group').unweighted(),
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: 1000,
    maxPixels: 1e8
  }).get('groups'));
  
  
  return sums_many.map(function(subList){
    return ee.Dictionary(subList).set('date',band) // I guess you want to retain your image ID
})
})

print(iteration, 'iteration')
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think this is the desired output? I would like to have sum counts for each land cover group (1 to 6), now I get groups with values like 0.991124625, none in [1;6]? And sorry for adding the `mean.combine(sum)` code in the post, that was a distraction.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I wasn't paying attention to what bands actually contain the landclasses and what have the area computation... Not sure if it can be done in once though, but a workaround could be to map over your bands and do the computation you would like?

Comment: yes, but that's supposedly very inefficient, my understanding is that what is costly is the reduceRegion(), not the reducer part of the operation. I would like to do only one reduceRegion() for 30 bands, and try to avoid to do 30 reduceRegion() for 1 band.